# How to change background color of a dialog input box using jQuery in IE 8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, input, dialog, background-color

I am having trouble doing this simple task of changing my input box color in a dialog created using jQueryUI in IE 8. 
Take a look at the 2 demo here: 
http://jsbin.com/ofare/94/edit#source  - not working in IE
http://jsfiddle.net/Cwm4W/10/ - working in IE but doesnt work in my dialog box

Both codes do not work when I run in my dialog box.

My code

```
<script>                 
     $('#test').css("background-color", 'gray');
     $( "#dialog-test" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                width: 350,
                height: 430,

                modal: true
     });
</script>

<div id="dialog-test">
<form>
    <table>
    <tr>
            <td>
                User Name
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"  id="test" />      
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the reasoning behind not creating the style in your CSS? jQuery does not need to be used here.

Comment: I want to add an option button to disable the input box. So, I need the box to change color to the user knows that that box is disabled without even clicking on it

Comment: What you're looking for is to use the attribute readonly="readonly" to achieve your ultimate goal.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried readonly, but it doesnt gray out the field in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dialog()` is a [JQueryUI function](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). Make sure you include it in your fiddle :)

This has a gray background in IE8, though my IETester doesn't really like it and alerts a couple unhelpful script errors: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/Cwm4W/18/

```
$(function(){
     $("#dialog-test").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                resizable: false,
                width: 350,
                height: 430,
                modal: true
     }).find('#test').css('background-color','gray');
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I wanted to input box ('test') background to be gray, but not the background of the dialog

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I copied parts of my code to the fiddle and it works but it still not working on my side. I will try to figure it out.